# Database error occurred in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Can someone help me whats wrong with my query? when I execute it the output shows like this.

```
Error Number: 1064
```

**You have an error in your**

> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO touristspot(TouristspotID, AccountID, CategoryID, Name, Description, street, city_area, city) Values(0, 111, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

my controller:

```
   public function manager_spotdetails(){


    $data = array(

        'CategoryID' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'Name' => $this->input->post('spotname'),
        'Description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'street' => $this->input->post('street'),
        'city_area' => $this->input->post('city_area'),
        'city' => $this->input->post('city')
    );

    $this->load->model('managerm');
    $data['cat'] = $this->managerm->category();
    $this->managerm->createspots($data);
    $this->load->view('manager_spotdetails', $data);


}


public function createTouristspot(){

    $this->load->model('managerm');
    $data['cat'] = $this->managerm->category();
    $this->load->view('manager_spotdetails');
}
```

my Model:

```
    public function createspots($data){


    $b = $_SESSION['accountid'];
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $spot_id= $this->db->insert_id();
    $sql3= "INSERT INTO touristspot(TouristspotID, AccountID, CategoryID, Name, Description, street, city_area, city) Values($spot_id, $b, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";      
    $this->db->query($sql3, $data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

    public function category(){
    $this->db->select('CategoryID');
    $this->db->select('CategoryType');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

my Views:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                         <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Category Type</span>
                        <select class="form-control" name="category">
                            <?php foreach($cat as $row) {?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row->CategoryID?>"><?php echo $row->CategoryType?></option>
                <?php }?>
                        </select>
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: I cannot save the the one that I inputted into the database

Comment: Go to `database.php` in config folder under application and go to `db_debug` and make it true like this `'db_debug'=>true,` Find the actual problem and solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding quotes the column **Name** read as Keyword in sql

```
$sql3= "INSERT INTO touristspot(`TouristspotID`, `AccountID`, `CategoryID`, `Name`, `Description`, `street`, `city_area`, `city`) Values('$spot_id','$b', '', '', '','', '', '')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your $sql3 string, Insert single quotes(') in VALUES:

```
$sql3= "INSERT INTO touristspot(`TouristspotID`, `AccountID`, `CategoryID`, `Name`, `Description`, `street`, `city_area`, `city`) VALUES('$spot_id', '$b', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: i have to put a single quote in every values?

Answer (score 0):

use this methods for insertion data

**controller**

```
$data = array(
      "COLUMN_NAME"=>$this->input->post("account_fname"),
      "COLUMN_NAME"=>$this->input->post("account_lname")
);
$insert = $this->Model_name->insert("table_name", $data);
```

**Model**

```
public function insert($table,$data){
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Method manager_spotdetails in Controller Should Be**

```
public function manager_spotdetails(){
$data = array(

    'AccountID'=>$_SESSION['accountid'],
    'CategoryID' => $this->input->post('category'),
    'Name' => $this->input->post('spotname'),
    'Description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
    'street' => $this->input->post('street'),
    'city_area' => $this->input->post('city_area'),
    'city' => $this->input->post('city')
);

$this->load->model('managerm');
$data['cat'] = $this->managerm->category();
$this->managerm->createspots($data);
$this->load->view('manager_spotdetails', $data);
```

}

**The Method createspots in Model Should Be**

```
public function createspots($data){
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->insert('touristspot', $data);
$this->db->trans_complete();
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

}

Hope It Will Works Fine. Make sure your array index name same as database table column name.